# Using .click or .trigger to auto open a lightbox with an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, joomla, lightbox

this is bothering me:

I have a lightbox on my website, this loads a survey. I wish to autoload the survey when a user visits the page. However using the .click function for jquery, it simply goes to the actual page rather than open up the survey page using lightbox (iframe).

```
<a id="surveyLoad" title="Iframe" 
href="http://www.surveygizmo.com" 
data-lightbox="group:mygroup2;width:600;height:400;scrolling:no">Survey</a>
```

**Jquery:**

```
if ($("#surveyLoad").length > 0) {
  $("#surveyLoad").trigger("click");
  $("#surveyLoad")[0].click();
 }
```

I tried using both .trigger and .click, .trigger didnt work and .click redirects me to the actual page of the survey. I have removed the actual link to the survey and replaced it with a general link.

Comment: which lightbox plugin are you using?

Comment: im using the one provided by the yootheme template, "widgetkit", im not too sure which version they use. Let me see if i can find it.

Comment: https://www.yootheme.com/widgetkit/examples/lightbox

Comment: YooTheme doesn't seem to give good documentation on its lightbox.  Usually, with other plugins, you can simply call a function that would show the lightbox.  Not too sure about this one

Comment: any recommendation on another lightbox that can pop-up on page load? Bearing in mind that i have to keep the other lightbox too, since we use that for other aspects of the site.

Comment: I thought maybe in my case, it was redirecting because the lightbox class had not finished loading (possibly).

Comment: I don't think that is the reason.  The way YooTheme seems to handle these lightboxes is to add some javascript that executes a user clicks on the link.  When a click is "simulated", since this is a valid <a> tag with a href value, the javascript is skipped, and you are redirected to the new page.  Try Fancybox or googling some "JQuery Lightbox Plugins"!

Comment: if it helps in lightbox.js, it says this version is based on fancybox